# Flexbox positioning of elements

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, responsive-design

Hi this is my example layout on mobile device.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-dust-xuurof?file=/src/styles.css

On the wider screen the third element must be the same width like a second yellow element. The second and the third element. The second and third items together are the same height as the first item. The html structure cannot change, I need use Flexbox, not css grid.

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
  flex-basis: 120px;
  height: 80px;
}

.two {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.three {
  background-color: green;
  height: 30px;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .one {}
  .two {}
  .three {}
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apply the height of `.one` to the container (since they're the same, right?). Switch to `flex-direction: column`. No changes to the HMTL. https://jsfiddle.net/hL85fkwq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the media query to account for this snippet.

You should see "Large Screen" results in the snippets "Full Page" mode.

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.two {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 4 1 auto;
}

.three {
  background-color: green;
  height: initial;
  flex: 4 1 auto;
}

@media screen and (width < 1024px) {
  .App {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .two {
    flex: 4 0 auto;
  }
  .three {
    height: 30px;
    flex: 4 0 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
</div>
```